# IP vs domain name when setting custom name servers

Tags: domain-name-system, ip

Is it better (for efficiency) to use an IP address when setting a custom name server for my domain name rather than a domain like ns1.myserver.com?

Comment: I can't figure out how this question could make sense. In what case do you have to choose between using a domain name or using an IP address?

Comment: This question is very vague; use IP address where? In general, using an IP address is best for daemons and servers in general.

Comment: Apologies for the vagueness--my understanding of how this works is limited. I have a domain registered with a company other than where my web site is being hosted, and thus need to point the domain to my web host.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you specify a name server, you need to provide an `NS` record. `NS` records always point to a name. See [Can the value for a NS record be an IP address?](https://serverfault.com/questions/100307/can-the-value-for-a-ns-record-be-an-ip-address)

```
$ host -t NS serverfault.com
serverfault.com name server ns3.serverfault.com.
serverfault.com name server ns4.serverfault.com.
serverfault.com name server ns1.serverfault.com.
serverfault.com name server ns2.serverfault.com.
```

Whatever hosts you list as your name servers must also resolve to an IP.

```
$ host ns3.serverfault.com
ns3.serverfault.com has address 69.59.196.217
```

Thus, if you're using an interface that is asking you to enter a name server's address, enter a DNS name.

Also, don't sweat the round-trip-time to find that A record -- the referring server also keeps the `A` record as "[glue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Circular_dependencies_and_glue_records)". That's why you usually also have to enter the IP address. When looking up the `NS` record, we get that additional data as well. With my registrar, I must first define a nameserver's name and IP combination before I can register the nameserver to the domain.

```
$ dig serverfault.com. @b.gtld-servers.net

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3 <<>> serverfault.com. @b.gtld-servers.net.
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 30818
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 3
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;serverfault.com.           IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
serverfault.com.    172800  IN      NS      ns1.serverfault.com.
serverfault.com.    172800  IN      NS      ns2.serverfault.com.
serverfault.com.    172800  IN      NS      ns3.serverfault.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.serverfault.com.        172800  IN      A       64.34.119.33
ns2.serverfault.com.        172800  IN      A       64.34.119.34
ns3.serverfault.com.        172800  IN      A       69.59.196.217

;; Query time: 151 msec
;; SERVER: 192.33.14.30#53(192.33.14.30)
;; WHEN: Mon Mar 12 22:37:41 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 135
```

Comment: I could have sworn I've been able to add IP addresses into the name server settings for a domain before. Oddly enough my registrar has two apparent ways to set this: one under "name servers" and the other under NS record of DNS. How are these different?

Comment: @chaiguy Gave you some updates on glue records... it is very likely that you did have to add addresses when specifying name servers.

Comment: I think I get it, cheers :)