# How to set up a DNS authoritative nameserver with just an IP?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I'm looking to set up my first DNS server, after having used registrar or web host provided DNS for years. It's going smoothly for the most part, but I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how to link it up to by registrar.

My setup is thus: I have configured the hostname on my server to be `ns1.example.com`. BIND is running on this server with a zone for `example.com` and records for `ns1.example.com` (resolving to its own public IP) as well as record for several other `*.example.com` subdomains.

I now want to make this server the authoritative DNS server for `example.com`. I had thought, perhaps naively, that I would be able to provide the IP address for this server to my registrar, and that they'd be able to set up an NS record for `example.com`. This appears to not be the case - [based on some research](https://serverfault.com/questions/100307/can-the-value-for-a-ns-record-be-an-ip-address), it appears I need an actual hostname for my NS servers.

I can't provide `ns1.example.com`, because it's a catch-22: in order to know which server `ns1.example.com` is, you need to look it up with `ns1.example.com`.

What is the solution to this? I can use my registrar-provided DNS for `example.com`, and then establish an A record for `ns1.example.com`, but I think that would mean I'd have to move all my other subdomain DNS records for `example.com` to my registrar's DNS. I'd be able to use the server as authoritative DNS for other domains, just not `example.com`. Is this correct?

I'm new to running my own DNS server, so I'm hoping there's an option to deal with this issue that I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parent zone hosts A records for the DNS servers. In this case the parent zone would be `.COM`

These A-records are often called "glue records" because while they don't really belong in the parent zone they are necessary to be able to locate the DNS server(s).

Comment: Hm, I'll have to look into how to do that. Thanks!